# Receive a single weight from scale Using a button press

Tags: c#, scale

I am tasked with creating a Windows form application for the factory i work for.
We will be weighing multiple bags, so every time the button is pressed it must send the weight that is currently on the scale. In other words just capture the current weight and wait for me to press the button again to capture the next bag that will be loaded on the scale. Currently it continuously receives data from the scale once the button is clicked and the result only flashes in my textbox. I want to change so it only receives one weight then stops. Can you please show me how i can accomplish this.

Thank you in advance

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace ScaleV5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort _serialPort;         //<-- declares a SerialPort Variable to be used throughout the form
        private const int BaudRate = 9600;      //<-- BaudRate Constant. 9600 seems to be the scale-units default value
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
            foreach (var portName in portNames)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);                  //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;                        //<-- Selects first entry (convenience purposes)
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
            if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
            if (_serialPort != null)
                _serialPort.Dispose();
            //<-- End of Block

            _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
            _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
            _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
            textBox1.Multiline = true;
            textBox1.Text += $"Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + $"\r\n";
                        
        }

        private delegate void Closure();
        private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
            else
            {
                int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
                int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
                if (nbrDataRead == 0)
                    return;
                string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                textBox1.Text = str.ToString();

                _serialPort.WriteLine("w");
                

            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
           
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serialPort.Close();
            this.Close();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
      

       
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you don't need to close and reopen the port each time you want to get valus from the device. 2) I suggest a more synchronous approach. At each button press send a  `"w"` then give the scale time to react and read the incoming data then stop it again by sending a `"w"`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply on my problem. Will you be able to give me a example of what you mean. I am a junior programmer and this is one of my first projects. Much appreciated.

Comment: Scales have two modes of operating 1) Continuous 2) Single measurement.  It is better to change code so program sends the command to read one measurement than to have operator push button.

Comment: @OnePunchMahn ok I posted an answer with an example. For the future: please choose more meaningful names for your buttons.  `button3_Click` doesn't tell us much. What you want is us to understand you and grasp the problem and context as fast as possible. This way you get better answers

Comment: @jdweng How will i go about changing the mode to single measurement? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. put the entire port instantiation and closing/opening code into the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox. When the user chooses a port you simply open it and leave it open. Opening and closing ports takes time. So you should keep it to a minimum.
2. When pressing the button you would only probe the scale via the port for the values. (If you really have 2 modes of operation choose the single measurement)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // probe device for value
    _serialPort.WriteLine("w");

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    string response = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
    // here parse the resonse to extract you value


    // stop the device
    _serialPort.WriteLine("w");
   
    textBox1.Multiline = true; // <- this code belongs into the constructor
    textBox1.Text += extractedStringValue;
                
 }
```

disclaimer: this code runs synchronously and will block the UI. It depends strongly on your device how long it need to responde to your first request of measurements. To avoid the blocking of the UI you would need to work with async/await.